# UIPopoverController deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated

I am getting a warning while using `UIPopoverController` , After reading apple doc i understood this is deprecated and we have to use `UIPopoverPresentationController`. Please anybody help me to to replace the below code .

```
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]   initWithContentViewController:viewDownloader];
[popover setPopoverContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 450)];
```

In another method

```
if (popover!=nil && popover.popoverVisible == YES)
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

I need to replace these codes , but can’t find any equivalent . Any help appreciated . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Google "UIPopoverPresentationController example," and you will see tons of tutorials.

Comment: Use UIPopoverPresentationController  : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIModalPresentationPopover

[UIModalPresentationPopover](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle) is replacement of `UIPopoverController`.

Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

```
ModalViewController *modal = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
modal.transitioningDelegate = self;
modal.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
modal.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectZero;
modal.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or else You can use below link.

[UIPopoverPresentationController](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-popovers-in-ios-9/)

Answer (score 1):

Below code to show `UIModalPresentationPopover` on menu button tapped from selected UITableViewCell;

```
-(void)menuButtonTapped:(UIButton *)button {

    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)[[button superview] superview];
    self.selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath: self.selectedIndexPath];
    CGRect rectOfCellInSuperview = [self.tableView convertRect: rectOfCellInTableView toView:_tableView.superview];
    rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width-50;

    MyMenuPopoverController *myMenuPopoverController= [[MyMenuPopoverController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    myMenuPopoverController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    myMenuPopoverController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
    myMenuPopoverController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = rectOfCellInSuperview;
    myMenuPopoverController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(250,(myMenuPopoverController.arrMenuOptions.count * 40));
}
```